# CSS specificity for elements with more than one class

Tags: css, css-specificity, memory-efficient

I am having an issue where I am unable to get the level of specificity I need to make some code work. I have a `<ul>` for which I want to make the backgrounds of the `<li>`'s change when hovered on with a fancy little slide-in animation.

I managed to get it working pretty well using a `linear-gradient` with a `transition` on `:hover`. I decided that I wanted to have the different list items have different background colors than each other, so I added three classes: `.red`, `.blue`, and `.gold`, and I figured I would just make everything with the `.level1` class have the required properties other than the linear gradient itself—namely, `background-size: 200% 100%`, `background-position:right bottom`, and  `transition:all 1s ease`, and then specify the linear gradient and color for each individual color class. I know this is all pretty intangible, but I will post my code below.

Here is what I was hoping to have (or something like it):

```
    body .push [class^="level1"] {
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-position:right bottom;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

    body .push [class^="level1"]:hover {
        background-position:left bottom;
    }

    body .push .level1.blue {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #282e59 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    }

    body .push .level1.red {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #94272a 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    }

    body .push .level1.gold {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #e5d037 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    }
```

But that doesn't work. For the values in the first class to take effect, I have to get rid of the first one `body .push [class^="level1"] { ... }` and put that information in the three color-specific ones, like

```
            body .push .level1.blue {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #282e59 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-position:right bottom;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

    body .push .level1.red {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #94272a 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-position:right bottom;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

    body .push .level1.gold {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #e5d037 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-position:right bottom;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }
```

Is there any way to consolidate that information?

Comment: Are you using `body` for specificity? If not then you should be able to discard it on all css rules.

Comment: Good point. I'm not really sure what I was thinking there, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is not specificity, but that your shorthand `background:` declaration is overwriting the position & size values in your original declaration. Try changing `background:` to `background-image:` in your overwrites:

```
body .push .level1.blue {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #282e59 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}

body .push .level1.red {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #94272a 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}

body .push .level1.gold {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e5d037 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have html like:

```
...
<li class="level1">...</li>
<li class="level1 red">...</li>
<li class="level1 gold">...</li>
<li class="level1 blue">...</li>
```

In that case you can change your code to

```
.push .level1 {
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

.push .level1:hover {
    background-position:left bottom;
}

.push .blue {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #282e59 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}

.push .red {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #94272a 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}

.push .gold {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e5d037 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I really appreciate it :) 
Sorry I can't upvote, I don't have 15 rep yet haha